# GitHub API - Basic Authorization (username:password) 401 status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, github-api

I am trying to use the Basic Authorization method that accepts username and password. I am working in React, using a fetch. It does not seem to work. It sends status 401 Unauthorized. I've no two-factor authentication. And yes, I have used PAT but I want to authenticate using username:password method. Kindly look at the code:

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/user", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${username}:${password}`)}`,
      "Content-Length": 0,
    },
  }).then((response) => response.status);
```

Comment: Github api uses OAuth 2 for authentication, basic authentication won't work

Comment: But the documentation says that the support will end in November. So, Basic Authentication should be working these days...?

Comment: i can see your problem. The documentation has stated basic authentication with CURL by inputting the password after the initial request.